# HTML Select Dropdown options overlap issue on backdrop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have small issue with HTML select dropdown options. I clicked on the HTML dropdown and without selecting any option from the dropdown moved my cursor to the "Show Backdrop" label. The options from the dropdown are now overlapping the backdrop.

[image]

An example can also be found at http://mansri.com/issues/select-dropdown/index.html

Below is my HTML, CSS and jQuery code.

**HTML Code**

```
<div style="margin-top: 120px; width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <a href="#" class="show-backdrop">Show Backdrop</a>
    <div class="backdrop">
            &nbsp;
    </div>
    <select>
        <option>Select Any</option>
        <option value="">sadf</option>
        <option value="">qewrqer</option>
        <option value="">xxccvcv</option>
        <option value="">;lkj;lkjdssf</option>
    </select>
    <br>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.backdrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.backdrop-show {
  display: block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.show-backdrop').hover(function(){
    $('.backdrop').addClass('backdrop-show');
});
```

On showing backdrop on hover, if the select dropdown options are showing, it should not overlap my backdrop.

Thanks in advance for giving me solution for this.

Comment: I'm unable to produce your described scenario:
Clicked on the HTML dropdown and without selecting any option from dropdown moved my courser to "Show Backdrop" label.

I did this and nothing happens no backdrop effect.

Comment: Hi Jazib, Please go to the given link and click on the select dropdown and without selecting any option or clicking anywhere move your mouse to the "Show Backdrop" label. Then you will see the scenario. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Yes, Manoj I have tried to produce your scenario but it's working fine. Kindly Check following video:
https://s.nimbusweb.me/video/1956851/3n9tixq6qt6vfuhsh8f0/1036172-hosOneSoeBJVi34q/1036172-Ah6xOPics2Ux9vr2/dropdown_issue.mp4

Comment: Hi Jazib, I am not sure why you are not getting that issue. I just recorded and uploaded in following link. please have a look.  http://mansri.com/issues/select-dropdown/issue-gif.html

Comment: Hmm, I'm using google chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: my version is 67.0.3396.99.

Comment: I just tried to produce your bug in window OS . In Linux it's working fine. Let me dubug the issue

Comment: Manoj sorry i was busy. Your Issue fixed or not?

Comment: Hi Jazib, it is not fixed.